# Django models: Why the name clash?

Tags: django, django-models

Firstly, I know how to fix the problem, I'm just trying to understand why it's occuring. The error message:

> users.profile: Reverse query name for field 'address' clashes with related field 'Address.profile'. Add a related_name a
>   rgument to the definition for 'address'.

And the code:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    country = fields.CountryField(default='CA')
    province = fields.CAProvinceField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    street3 = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)

class Profile(Address):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile')
    primary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, unique=True)
```

If I understand correctly, this line:

```
address = models.ForeignKey(Address, unique=True)
```

Will cause an attribute to be added to the `Address` class with the name `profile`. What's creating the *other* "profile" name?

---

What if I don't need a reverse name? Is there a way to disable it? Addresses are used for a dozen things, so most of the reverse relationships will be blank anyway.

Is there a way to copy the address fields into the model rather than having a separate table for addresses? Without Python inheritance (this doesn't make sense, and if an Model has 2 addresses, it doesn't work).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) it says:

If you'd prefer Django didn't create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+'. For example, this will ensure that the User model won't get a backwards relation to this model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
```

but I never tried it myself....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the errant `profile` field is coming from… But one way to find out would be: temporary remove `address = models.ForeignKey(…)` from Profile, `./manage.py shell`, `from ... import Address` then see what `Address.profile` will tell you.

I don't think there is any official way to inherit only the fields from some other Model without using inheritance… But you could fake it like this (where `SourceModel` is, eg, `Address` and `TargetModel` is, eg, `Profile`):

```
for field in SourceModel._meta.fields:
    TargetModel.add_to_class(field.name, copy.deepcopy(field))
```

(this is coming from [Django's ModelBase `__new__` implementation](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L155))

Comment: Did what you said. `AttributeError: type object 'Address' has no attribute 'profile'`. Actually.... without naming it it's not giving me an error anymore. I'm not sure what I changed >.< Maybe it was cached for a bit or something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to disable the reverse name.

I've just done a quick `grep` over the code and it doesn't look like there is any logic which will bypass setting up the `related_name` field on the related model.

Answer (score 0):

For Example: Add just '+'

```
class GeneralConfiguration(models.Model):

created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=settings.DEFAULT_DATE)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=settings.DEFAULT_DATE)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='+')
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='+')
```